# Receiving the sent data from Laravel to Logstash in Kibana

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, elk

I am using Laravel to send my logs to Logstash and I want to show them in Kibana. Here is what I did:

In `logging.php`:

```
   'logstash' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via'    => \App\LogstashLogger::class,
        'host'   => env('LOGSTASH_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'   => env('LOGSTASH_PORT', 9200),
    ],
```

In `LogstashLogger` class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: farshad
 * Date: 8/5/19
 * Time: 1:19 PM
 */

namespace App;

use Monolog\Formatter\LogstashFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\SocketHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class LogstashLogger {
    /**
     * @param array $config
     * @return LoggerInterface
     */
    public function __invoke(array $config): LoggerInterface
    {
        $handler = new SocketHandler("udp://{$config['host']}:{$config['port']}");
        $handler->setFormatter(new LogstashFormatter(config('app.name')));
        return new Logger('logstash.main', [$handler]);
    }
}
```

In tinker when I run this command:

```
>>> Log::channel('logstash')->info('Hello logstash!');
```

I get null back without any error in my logs. It should mean that the data was sent to Logstash successfully. How can I now get the data from Logstash and show it in Kibana? When I want to create an index pattern it won't accept any name. I don't know how to check if I received the data in Logstash or how to show it in Kibana.